# Behavior of the body after the animation end on the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I made a `CSS` animation on the body, going from one color to the other for like 10 seconds, only showing one image and one `paragraph`, and ignoring the rest of the `paragraphs` and other stuff written in my `HTML` code.

When the animation is finished, I would like that the body displays the actual `HTML` content (other `paragraphs` and `DIV`'s, etc.). Now that is the problem, I tried with opacity and setting it to 0 during the animation and then resetting it to 1 after the animation ends but I could not do it? Could you help me? I created the animations in `JS` with event listeners and keyframes in `CSS`.

```js
let backColor = document.querySelector('body');
let banner = document.querySelector('#banner p');
let img = document.querySelector('#banner img');

function myMove() {
  backColor.style.WebkitAnimation = 'mymove 7s 1s 1 forwards';
  backColor.style.animation = 'mymove 7s 1s 1 forwards';
}

backColor.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});

backColor.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
});

myMove();

function yourMove() {
  banner.style.WebkitAnimation = 'yourmove 6s 4s 1';
  banner.style.animation = 'yourmove 6s 4s 1';
}

banner.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  this.style.opacity = 0;
});

banner.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  this.style.opacity = 1;
});

yourMove();

function hisMove() {
  img.style.WebkitAnimation = 'hismove 3s 6s 1';
  img.style.animation = 'hismove 3s 6s 1';
}

img.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  this.style.opacity = 0;
});

img.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  this.style.opacity = 1;
});

hisMove();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    background-color: white;
  }
  to {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

#banner p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  left: 35%;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes yourmove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hismove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <p>In the loving memory of <br />Kobe Bryant (1978 - 2020)</p>
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tiE7aa9HTec/maxresdefault.jpg" width="450" height="300">
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <!-- rest of the html content -->
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="kobe.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @gforce301 here is the code man

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't had make it this way,but it's fixed:

```js
let backColor = document.querySelector('body');
let banner = document.querySelector('#banner p');
let img = document.querySelector('#banner img');

function myMove() {
  backColor.style.WebkitAnimation = 'mymove 7s 1s 1 forwards';
  backColor.style.animation = 'mymove 7s 1s 1 forwards';
}

backColor.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  backColor.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});

backColor.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  backColor.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
});

myMove();

function yourMove() {
  banner.style.WebkitAnimation = 'yourmove 6s 4s 1';
  banner.style.animation = 'yourmove 6s 4s 1';
}

banner.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  banner.style.opacity = 0;
});

banner.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  banner.style.opacity = 1;
});

yourMove();

function hisMove() {
  img.style.WebkitAnimation = 'hismove 3s 6s 1';
  img.style.animation = 'hismove 3s 6s 1';
}

img.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  img.style.opacity = 0;
});

img.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  img.style.opacity = 1;
});

hisMove();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    background-color: white;
  }
  to {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

#banner p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  left: 35%;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes yourmove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hismove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <p>In the loving memory of <br />Kobe Bryant (1978 - 2020)</p>
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tiE7aa9HTec/maxresdefault.jpg" width="450" height="300">
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <!-- rest of the html content -->
    RIP RIP RIP RIP RIP RIP
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="kobe.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but I would like the background of the body becomes white after the animation finish

Comment: Made the modification. This has to be tweaked you get the idea: one more keyframe